# Potential resource leak: 'httpclient' may not be closed at this location

Tags: java, memory-leaks, eclipse-oxygen

Getting the error mentioned in the title in the line

> return responseXML.toString();

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("test");
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "test");
httppost.setHeader("content-type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(NameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    StringBuffer responseXML = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    try {
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseXML.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println( responseXML.toString());
    return responseXML.toString();
```

Comment: Where is httpClient initialised, and is it autocloseable? It may be possible to do a try-with-resources here: try (HttpClient httpClient = ....) { }

Comment: added httpclient initialisation

Answer (score 1):

You could use a try-with-ressources : `try(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient)`
(or whereever you get the client from) or you could use a finally where you close the htppClient:

```
finally {
httpClient.close();
}
```

Comment: there is no httpClient.close ()

Answer (score 1):

As noted, try-with-resources ought to help.

To exploit try-with-resources your HttpClient needs to be of a **autocloseable** type: one that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. Assuming you're using Apache httpcomponents...

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
   // note the CloseableHttpClient which allows this to happen.
}
```

There are other opportunities in your code for this pattern, for example where you have the buffered reader.

See this [tutorial on try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).